# Calculating time of first and last value above threshold

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a signal in Simulink (R2015b) that corresponds to a Power output. The signal is a discrete scalar in 1 minute intervals.
Every day at a certain Time (i.e. 00:00) i want to calculate the times of the day before (or index since values are discrete in 1 min intervals) where the signal crossed a certain threshold for the first and last time (see image).

I would like to implement this in a Simulink function block if possible unless there is a more simple solution.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [find](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function for this. I don't know if this can be implemented as a Simulink function block, I have no clue about Simulink:

```
% fake some data
t = 0:200;
signal = 100*exp(-((t - 100)/50).^2) + randn(1,201)*10;

% plot signal
plot(t, signal);

threshold = 50;

% find first above threshold
ind1 = find(signal > threshold, 1, 'first');

% find last above threshold
ind2 = find(signal > threshold, 1, 'last');

% plot it
hold on;
plot([1 1] * t(ind1), [0 100], 'r-', [1 1] * t(ind2), [0 100], 'r-');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this awesome explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Given that `t`, `signal` and `threshold` have the data you talk about, another option is:

```
getfield(t(signal>threshold),{[1 sum(signal>threshold)]})
```

this will give you the first and last values of time `t` where `signal>threshold`...